# Marble ring: no two blacks are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

**Question**: How many ways are there to arrange $20$ marbles, $6$ black and $14$ white, in a ring (circular arrangement) such that no two of the black marbles are next to each other?

**Comments**: It is easier to find the probability, as there are shortcuts one can make without having to find the number of ways. It is also much easier to do it as if the marbles were in a row. But, in a ring, finding the number of ways is harder. Any ideas?

Comment: It's the same as finding the number of partions of $14$ into a ring of $6$ positive numbers, which is the same as the number of ways of partitioning $8$ into a ring of $6$ non-negative numbers. You might have to use inclusion-exclusion to deal with the rotation issue.

Comment: Right, what I'm having trouble with is the rotation issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the condition, glue a white marble to the right of each black marble. Now the task is to arrange 6 black(+white) marbles and 8 white marbles. In principle, there are $14\choose 6$ ways to do so.
However, (most) patterns come in sets of 14 differing only by rotation. 
And some (namely $7\choose 3$) point-symmetric patterns come only in sets of 7 differing by rotation.
We should also check for patterns with 7fold or 14fold symmetry, but they can be excluded because there are only 6 black marbles.

In total there are
$$ \frac17{7\choose 3}+\frac1{14}\left({14\choose 6}-{7\choose 3}\right)=217$$
patterns up to rotation (what about reflection?).

Comment: Magnificent! I've +1d and given the check mark since I think this is the simplest way somebody could have shown it. One question though. 

I understood the 14-fold symmetry part. About the 7-fold symmetry, I didn't quite get that. Why those special 7-fold symmetry cases? And what if, instead of $14$, we had an odd number?

Comment: @AhaanRungta:  There are some patterns where the black marbles are in opposite pairs.  In those cases, there are only $7$ distinct patterns that can be created by rotation, not $14$  You could try it by hand with four white and two black to see what is going on.

Comment: Hm, but how did you obtain the $7$? Sorry for being such a nitwit.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{8+5}{5}$ partitions of $8$ into $6$ ordered non-negative numbers. Call this set $T$.

There is an action of $\mathbb Z_6$ on $T$ defined by rotation.  Then $T/G$ is the set of orbits under this action. Each orbit must have size $1,2,3,6$.

First, convince yourself that there cannot be any orbits of size $1,2$.

If there was an orbit of size $1$, then all the elements of your partition would be the same, which isn't possible since $6$ is not a factor of $8$.

If there was an orbit of size $2$, then there would be a partition of $8$ into three equal numbers.

So there can only be orbits of size $3$ and $6$.

An element of $T$ has orbit size $3$ if it is composed of $2$ identical partitions of $4$ into three non-negative values. There are $\binom{4+2}{2}=15$ such elements of $T$.

There are thus $\binom{8+5}{5}-\binom{4+2}{2}$ elements of $T$ that are in orbits of size $6$.

This means that the number of elements of $T/G$ is:

$$\frac{1}{3}\binom{4+2}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\left(\binom{8+5}{5}-\binom{4+2}{2}\right)$$

More generally, if there are $pa$ white balls and $pb$ black balls, with $p$ prime (or $p=1$), $(a,b)=1$ and $a>b$, then there are:

$$\frac{1}{a}\left((p-1)\binom{a}{b} + \binom{pa}{pb}\right)$$

(This formula is more akin to Hagen's answer, with mine adding some messy $-1$s. But they are the same answer.)

It's more complicated when $p$ is not prime. That's when you need a more complicated inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: Ah, wonderful! I think Hagen has got it exactly right but I have +1d your post nevertheless, for your effort! :)

Comment: Ah, I miscomputed $\binom{8+5}{5}$, amongst other things.

Comment: In fact, you get $217$, which agrees with Hagen

Comment: Yep, was just about to post that, @RossMillikan. :)